# Joomla Invalid token / Session timeout issue

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.1, jomsocial

I have a site that is implemented in Joomla 3.1.5 on which the following are installed

1. http://www.joomlart.com/joomla/templates/ja-muzic --> This is the theme
2. http://www.jomsocial.com/ --> Used as the community plugin
3. http://www.kunena.org/ --> The forums plugin
4. http://getk2.org/blog --> The Blog plugin

Of course there are some custom components and modules that are implemented.

The issue i am facing is that there is some kind of conflict happening between the sessions i think. What happens is that the session times out randomly or i get a error message as "Invalid Token". All this even when the pages is being used continuously.

I have checked the value in the back-end config , Session Lifetime is set to 60 and Session Handler is set to Database

Let me know if you need more info.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This question is about Joomla management, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i have it posted there as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually caused by JomSocial and the cache plugin. Try disabling caching or changing the order of the cache plugin.

Worst case scenario, you can disable the "Invalid Token" issue in the code - but that solution would be a bit extreme (but, if all else fails, it's the only solution).

PS: For an in-depth about the "Invalid Token" error, you can check here: http://www.itoctopus.com/invalid-token-on-joomla-login